# Cannot construct instance of class although at least one Creator exists

Tags: kotlin, jackson, deserialization

I am having the following problem in Kotlin when deserializing a `LocationGeneric` with Jackson. It is a case when I add no extra info to the abstract class I use to construct the concrete classes. It works good when I deserialize `LocationOne` or `LocationTwo`.

This is the code I have written:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, 
        property = "type", visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes(
        JsonSubTypes.Type(value = LocationOne::class, name = "ONE"),
        JsonSubTypes.Type(value = LocationTwo::class, name = "TWO"),
        JsonSubTypes.Type(value = LocationGeneric::class, name = "GENERIC_1"),
        JsonSubTypes.Type(value = LocationGeneric::class, name = "GENERIC_2")
)
abstract class Location(
        val type: String
)

class LocationGeneric(
        type: String
): Location(type)

class LocationOne(
        type: String,
        val somethingSpecific: String
): Location(type)

class LocationAirport(
        type: String,
        val somethingElse: String
): Location(type)
```

This is the error I am getting:

> Cannot construct instance of `Location` (although at least one Creator
>   exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or
>   property-based Creator)

I tried changing the abstract class to an open class, but had no luck so far. I works for the other cases. Why doesn't it find the default Kotlin constructor in the `LocationGeneric` case? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I had was that I somehow Jackson lost visibility of the constructor, so I provided a default implementation for the generic cases and annotated the constructor and attributes of my generic implementation.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
        property = "type", visible = true, defaultImpl = LocationGeneric::class)
@JsonSubTypes(
        JsonSubTypes.Type(value = LocationOne::class, name = "ONE"),
        JsonSubTypes.Type(value = LocationTwo::class, name = "TWO")
)
abstract class Location(
        val type: String
)

class LocationGeneric @JsonCreator constructor(
        @JsonProperty("type") type: String
): Location(type)
```

This also allows me to add an `init` to handle weird mapping cases.